# Moving label of seaborn color bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I've got a seaborn heat map with a labelled color bar using:

```
seaborn.heatmap(df, cbar_kws = {'label': 'Label for color bar axis'})
```

but the colorbar's label overlaps with its tick labels. Is there a way to reposition this label further from the ticks (in my case, further to the right) like the 'padding' options for a normal matplotlib plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately `cbar_kws` doesn't accept the `labelpad` argument. Therefore one way to add some padding to the labels will be to access the colorbar after it has been drawn.

You can use `ax.collections[0].colorbar` to get access to the `matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar` object. This then lets you use the colobar as you normally would with matplotlib. So, you can use `set_label()` to set your colorbars label, and you can use the `labelpad=` argument:

```
import seaborn as sns

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12) # random data
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)

cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.set_label('Label for colour bar axis', labelpad=40)

plt.show()
```

[image]